# Just window picker applet and border-less windows from Ubuntu Netbook Remix?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook-remix

[Ubuntu Netbook Remix - Overview](https://launchpad.net/netbook-remix) lists several packages that provide the functionally for Ubuntu Netbook Remix. I would like just the feature of having a window's decorations and title info to be displayed in the GNOME panel while that info and the border is removed from the window when in full screen. Adding the window-picker-applet to the panel adds the info to the panel but does not remove it from around the window.

How can I get the no longer needed border info removed from around the window? (without the complete Netbook Remix)

Answer (score 1):

[Maximus](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hu/oneiric/maximus) is the program that strips the title bar off the windows in Ubuntu Netbook Remix.

To install it, and tell it not to maximize windows (if that bugs you) do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install maximus
$ gconftool --type bool --set /apps/maximus/no_maximize true
```

You may also need to add an entry to your Startup Applications to launch Maximus when you log in.

(Tung Nguyen [mentions tantalisingly](http://tung.spheredev.org/site/node/70) that he achieved the same effect using a Metacity theme, but doesn't say how.)